# SPL_AUTOLOAD_REGISTER only registering

Tags: php

I'm using

```
function Autoload($ClassName) {
    if (is_readable(CLASSES.'/' . strtolower($ClassName) . '.class')){
        require(CLASSES.'/' . strtolower($ClassName) . '.class');
    }
}
spl_autoload_register("Autoload");
$site = new site();
$theme = new theme();
```

for an autoload function of classes that I'll be using.
When I try to use $theme->function inside of my themes directory I'm getting

```
 Undefined variable: theme in
```

I can fix this by placing `$theme = new theme();` at the top of the php file calling it, but to my understanding the autoload was to get rid of the need to do that. Is there something wrong with the code I'm using to register the classes or am I misunderstanding the reason behind autoload?

My Old Method

```
function LoadClasses() {
     foreach(glob(CLASSES.'/'.'*.class') as $classfile) {
             require $classfile;
       }
}
```

Comment: autoload doesn't eliminate the need to instantiate the objects . docs : https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: Okay, so it will still need to be instantiated in pages that use it. What's the advantage to how I used to load classes? Editing post to show my old method.